Dealing with interactive function in a script in R
Within an R script, I want to use a function that prompts the user for additional input. I already know the proper response, but there is no function argument available to provide the input. Can I make this run non-interactively, in general?
Specific case that's raised this question: I want to "clone" an renv environment into a temp directory with a script, using only a lock file. My first attempt was to:

Create temp directory
Copy lock file into temp directory
Run renv::init()

But renv::init() sees the pre-existing lockfile and asks how I would like to proceed. I want to "1: Restore the project from the lockfile.". Can I specify this in the script?
My current workaround is:

Create temp directory
Run renv::init()
Replace the initialized lockfile with the one I want to use.
Run renv::restore(prompt=FALSE)

(I don't know if this is good practice with renv in the first place. I'm open to comments challenging my whole approach, but I'm mainly interested in the answer to the more general question).

Why are you using macros (scripts) instead of functions?  The latter are much more powerful and useful

@CarlWitthoft Doesn’t that completely depend on the use-case? Scripts are command-line utilities. They are not substitutes for R functions (or vice-versa).

@KonradRudolph They (scripts) have their place,  but I don't think this is one of them :-) .   I've dealt with too many co-workers who use only scripts, manually changing variable values; and who have no concept of environments at all.
